# Await TronWeb send function to finish

Tags: blockchain, tron, tronweb

Hi Im new in tron so I have succefully implemented read functions in smartcontract and also write but the issue im facing is how do I wait for the transaction to finish so I can display its result in tronWeb. I do know how to do it in ethereum 0.x & 1.x but having no luck in tronWeb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I was able to wait for the transaction. I have to put the flag shouldPollResponse = true in the transaction like

```
 var demo = await tokenContract.claimAirdrop().send({
    feeLimit: 100000000,
    shouldPollResponse:true,
    callValue:  0,
  })
```

where **function** should be called **async** (Rule for using await), **tokenContract** is my contract instance and **claimAirdrop** is my contract functions